# Get Calculated Field from Eloquent only when it was declared

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm working with Eloquent and Laravel 5, added a field at `$appends` attribute on model and a mutator to get it value. My issue is, how get this field only when it is called?

```
    public static $model = 'Model';
    protected $table = 'table';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idtable';   
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $appends = ['DescComposta'];

    //Mutators
    public function getDescCompostaAttribute()
    {
        return $this->attributes['desc_composta'] = 'yes';
    }
```

Thank you all!

Comment: What do you mean "when it is called"? Where else shouldn't it appear?

Comment: If you only want it when called you should not make it a accessor (not mutator), just make it a normal function.

Comment: @Jerodev, yes, only appear when i called it on my query.

Comment: @ThomasMoors i wrote a function that add the attribute only, but i dont know how use it, i'm using eager loading to call, but it's returning error.